# Strange behavior when trying to source AWS environment variables from .sh file

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, unix

To quickly switch identities while using the AWS CLI I have a folder of downloaded credentials (csv files).  I hear there are more sophisticated ways to switch profiles but this way works for me and I've been too lazy to change it.  I tried to change one of them into a shell script that I could source:

```
# identity.sh
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='AKIABLAHBLAHKQKLQLGA'
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='secretblahblahblah'
```

If I copy/paste these two lines one at a time into my session, everything works fine.  But if I source the file - `. ~/credentials/identity.sh` the variables are corrupted.  It seems like my shell script thinks the first variable has a newline in it.  To illustrate:

```
$ export | grep AWS
"eclare -x AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="AKIABLAHBLAHKQKLQLGA
"eclare -x AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="secretblahblahblah
```

If I export the variables one at a time via copy/paste the output is as follows:

```
$ export | grep AWS
declare -x AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="AKIABLAHBLAHKQKLQLGA"
declare -x AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="secretblahblahblah"
```

It will surprise no one to learn that the CLI does not work when i try to source the file:

```
$ aws s3 ls
Invalid header value 'AWS AKIABLAHBLAHKQKLQLGA\r:blahblah='
```

Now this has been more of a curious puzzle than an actual showstopper issue, but I've tried various approaches to solving this:

- Both variables on one line without a newline separated by && or ;
- Double quotes, single quotes, no quotes.
- Different editors for the file (the \r made me think that the editor was using the old Mac \r convention for newlines but even using nano and vi the same issue occurred)
- Regenerating credentials (the first secret had a slash in it).
- Permissions on the .sh file (you don't need -x to source variables and adding -x doesn't have any effect)

Anyone have a clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely the `identity.sh` file was created on Windows machine and has unprintable DOS characters. You can check it by using `cat -t`:

> -t      Display non-printing characters

```
$ cat -t identity.sh
```

will show you the control characters. You can convert it to Mac by using `dos2unix` command. If you don't have `dos2unix` installed:

```
$ brew install dos2unix
```

Another option is to create that file scratch on Mac using `vi` or your favorite editor.

```
NAME
       dos2unix - DOS/Mac to Unix and vice versa text file format converter

SYNOPSIS
           dos2unix [options] [FILE ...] [-n INFILE OUTFILE ...]
           unix2dos [options] [FILE ...] [-n INFILE OUTFILE ...]

DESCRIPTION
       The Dos2unix package includes utilities "dos2unix" and "unix2dos" to convert plain text files in DOS or Mac format to Unix format and vice versa.
```

Comment: It actually had \r in there... my text editor claimed to be using unix line ending characters but wasn't.  and it turns out that if you edit it in nano it preserves the line ending convention even if you delete the newline and re-insert it.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, actually it was the original CSV downloaded from AWS IAM that had ctrl-m (\r) characters.  Once I edited that each editor decided to be really helpful and preserve that convention.